# Linking buttons not working in actionscript - flash cs4, AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4

I have 6 buttons on the same layer, all with hover over effects and the sort. I assigned each one an instance name, and tried to make actionscript to link each image to google, however the following code is not working:

```
function init():void {
    blogButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    portfolioButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    aboutButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    signButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    contactButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
}

function onActionPerformed(e:MouseEvent):void {
    switch(e.currentTarget) {
       case homeButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_blank"); break;
       case blogButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
       case portfolioButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
       case aboutButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
       case signButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
       case contactButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
    }
}
```

No errors, or compiling errors, just doesn't go anywhere.

**EDIT** The code has been modified slightly, however still not functioning I made a link to download the most current fla file:
http://danlamanna.com/misc/navigation.fla

Comment: if you put trace(e.currentTarget) as the first line of the onActionPerformed() method does it output what you expect?

Comment: No, however I've never done output with flash before, so should I expect google to pop up in the movie window, or open my default browser? Either way it does neither.

Comment: well if it's not generating any output when you click the buttons then your problem is before the method call. Did you try the trace statement? It outputs to the output panel in flash. At the beginning of your app try coding : trace("i'm useful for debugging")

Comment: I did one before the first function, it read that, I did one at the end of the first function and it did NOT read that, and then I did one in between the two and it read that. So it must not be processing the init function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning on leaving your code on the timeline, and your listeners only need to be set at runtime then you don't really need to wrap the listener instantiation in a function as you have it now.  Just take them out of the function and put them above the onActionPerformed function like so:

```
blogButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
portfolioButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
aboutButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
signButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
contactButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);

function onActionPerformed(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
     switch(e.currentTarget) 
     {
         case homeButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_blank"); break;
         case blogButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
         case portfolioButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
         case aboutButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
         case signButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
         case contactButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;

     }

}
```

If you need to dynamically add and remove the listeners at later times, try something like this:

```
addListeners();

function addListeners():void
{
    blogButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    portfolioButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    aboutButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    signButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    contactButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
}

function removeListeners():void
{
    blogButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    homeButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    portfolioButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    aboutButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    signButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
    contactButton.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
}

function onActionPerformed(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch(e.currentTarget)
    {
        case homeButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_blank"); break;
        case blogButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
        case portfolioButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
        case aboutButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
        case signButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
        case contactButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not running the function init so the listeners are not being set.

```
init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add a call to your init() function. Use the following:

```
function init():void 
{
        blogButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
        homeButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
        portfolioButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
        aboutButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
        signButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);
        contactButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onActionPerformed);

}// end function

function onActionPerformed(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
 switch(e.currentTarget) 
 {
  case homeButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_blank"); break;
  case blogButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
  case portfolioButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
  case aboutButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
  case signButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;
  case contactButton: navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://google.com"), "_self"); break;

 }// end switch

}// end function

init();
```